# How Nested Loops To Append Objects Into A List Works in A Single Line for loops?

Tags: python, class, nested

I don't understand what does this block of code do

example = [ [ sudoku(x,y,dimension) for x in range (dimension) ] for y in range (dimension)]

dimension is a variable that user inputs , sudoku is a class constructor. could someone explain me - or restructure this code to multi line version ? thanks.

Comment: Your question requires more clarity. Are you trying to get an explanation on what a specific line of code does? If so, what don't you understand? Adding more clarity to your question will attract more people which will ultimately get you the help you want.

Answer (score 0):

Imma write that in your favoured stile:

```py
example = []
for y in range(dimension):
    temp = []
    for x in range(dimension):
        temp.append(Sudoku(x, y, dimension)
    example.append(temp)
```

Sudoku is a Class-Name so it should be written in Uppercase.

Suppose your local variable is 3, this would result in

```
[
    [Sudoku(0, 0, 3), Sudoku(1, 0, 3), Sudoku(2, 0, 3)], 
    [Sudoku(0, 1, 3), Sudoku(1, 1, 3), Sudoku(2, 1, 3)], 
    [Sudoku(0, 2, 3), Sudoku(1, 2, 3), Sudoku(2, 2, 3)]
]
```

Comment: thank you very much! i totally understood it now.